# PHP separate array elements in foreach based on common values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have the following array coming from database:

```
$tags = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [tag_name] => Testing/EOC
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [tag_name] => Technology Tips
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [tag_name] => Student Engagement
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [tag_name] => Flipped Classroom
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 1
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [tag_name] => Blended Instruction
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 1
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [tag_name] => Differentiated Instruction
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 1
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7
                [tag_name] => Bootcamp
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 1
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 8
                [tag_name] => Mathematical Practices 1
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 1
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9
                [tag_name] => Mathematical Practices 2
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 2
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
                [tag_name] => Mathematical Practices 3
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 2
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11
                [tag_name] => Mathematical Practices 4
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 2
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [id] => 12
                [tag_name] => Mathematical Practices 5
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 2
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [id] => 13
                [tag_name] => Mathematical Practices 6
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 2
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [id] => 14
                [tag_name] => Mathematical Practices 7
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 2
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [id] => 15
                [tag_name] => Mathematical Practices 8
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 2
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16
                [tag_name] => Pre-Algebra
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 3
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [id] => 17
                [tag_name] => Sets and Venn Diagrams
                [description] => 
                [category] => Category 3
            )
    )
```

Right now I am just looping through like so:

```
<ul>
                    <? foreach($tags as $tag): ?>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="tag" name="tags[]" value="<?= $tag['id']; ?>">
                            <label><?= $tag['tag_name']; ?></label>
                        </li>
                    <? endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

However, what I really want to do is separate the tags and list them in three sections (probably their own separate divs) based on the three different categories. Basically I want to have three columns each with the Category Name as the heading with the proper tags listing below it. Not sure how to accomplish this in the loop and maintain them all as inputs in the same form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Group them by categories:

```
$categoryToTag = array();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if (!isset($categoryToTag[$tag['category']])) $categoryToTag[$tag['category']] = array();
    $categoryToTag[$tag['category']][] = $tag;
}
```

2 Loop over the categories and output the tags:

```
foreach ($categoryToTag as $category => $categoryTags) {
    echo 'Category '.$category.' begin';
    foreach ($categoryTags as $tag) echo $tag;
}
```

Comment: The conditional declaration is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a table:

```
<table>
<?php
// group the sub-arrays of your initial array by category
$cats = array();
foreach($tags as $tag){
$cats[$tag["category"]][] = array($tag["id"], $tag["tag_name"]);
}
// display the names of the categories in the header row of the table
print("<tr><th>".implode("</th><th>", array_keys($cats))."</th></tr>");
// create another row
print("<tr>");
// iterate over the categories – display each category in a single table cell
foreach($cats as $cat){
print("<td>");
// iterate over the sub-arrays of each category
    foreach($cat as $val){
    print("<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"tag\" name=\"tags[]\" value=\"{$val[0]}\">
                            <label>{$val[1]}</label><br/>");
    }
print("</td>");
}
print("</tr>");
?>
</table>
```